# Can't do a tableView Cell Action

Tags: tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` and I want there to link to the Apple website when the user taps the first cell or row in the `UITableView`. This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
if (indexPath == 0) {

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get some basics of Objective C. Check these to get the knowledge of `UITableView` delegate & datasource methods [UITableView Delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) & [UITableView DataSource methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). 
For your question, you have to use this method:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

In this method, check for selected row and write your code accordingly. You can open link in `UIWebView` or Safari.